# Создание пользователя в базе mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите разобраться в архитектуре приложений.

Как реализовать регистрацию на сайте. Допустим, я создал вот такую форму:

```
<form action="1.php">
<input type="text" name="login"  value="your login" />
<input type="password" name="pass" value="pass" />
<input type="text" name="address" value="address"  />
<input type="submit" value="submit"  />
</form>
```

Хочу, чтобы в БД создался пользователь с правами и именем введенного логина.

```
<?php
$db_host='localhost';
$db_login=$_GET["login"];
$db_password=$_GET["password"];
$db_database='wwot';
$db_login2='root';
$db_password2='';
$connection=mysql_connect($db_host,$db_login2,$db_password2) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO $db_login@'localhost'
 IDENTIFIED BY 'ty' WITH GRANT OPTION;") or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Но так требует права админа, чтобы добавить пользователя.
Я совсем новичок, поэтому подскажите принцип создания пользователя.
Может можно заносить логины в отдельную таблицу, а потом всем им давать права? Если да, то скажите как.

Comment: То, что вы хотите сделать возможно только на выделенном сервере, когда соединение с базой идет под абсолютным root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Говорите регистрация на сайте? Помоему вы путаете пользователей сайта и пользователей базы данных. Если хотите сделать регистрацию пользователей сайта, то вам надо завести отдельную таблицу для пользователей. Если всё же хотите добавлять пользователей мускула через веб шелл, то рекомендую для этого [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/)

Answer (score 4):

> хочу чтобы в создалось в БД
> пользователь  с правами именем
> введенного логина.

Теперь по-русски можно?!

Что хотим получить в итоге-то?

Пользователя в БД или Пользователя для БД?
Для каких нужд? хотим сделать Хостинг чтобы пользователям предоставлять БД и место под сайт?

На хостинге не шибко удастся такое сделать, сервер тут нужен с полным доступом + самописными скриптами для создания home папок на сервере + создание пользователей ftp+MySql.

Есть ли смысл с этим запариваться на php? не проще купить сервер с панелью, допустим ISP Manager?

Comment: Я плохо разбираюсь в Mysql,поэтому может говорю чушь.Хотел чтобы для каждого логина была создана отдельная таблица MYSQL.Хотя,возможно, это не удачное решение.

Comment: Напиши задачу конкретнее!